# React Native | Navigator talking back to Initial Page

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image]

I have this navigator Setup on my Routes Page and I am expecting that when I press this.props.navigation.goback function it should take me to the second page if I am on the third page but apparently it is taking me to the first page.

Even with the natural goback Behavior of Android or IOS, it's taking me to the First Page.

I navigate Via

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screens')
```

NavigatorPage: Here I am using DrawerNavigator

```
import {   createAppContainer ,createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Dashboard from './pages/dashboard';
import Splash from './pages/Splash';
import Readmore from './pages/readmore';
import Tabs from './pages/tab';
import Check from './pages/checking';
import Search from './pages/searchpage';
import SideMenu from './componenet/sideMenu'
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 // Prac: { screen:  Check},
 Splash :{ screen:  Splash},
  Dashboard: { screen:  Dashboard},
    Readmore: { screen: Readmore },
    Tabs: { screen: Tabs },
    Search: { screen: Search }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 300,
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    }
   });
  export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Edit ONE After doing this

```
    const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
 // Prac: { screen:  Check},
 stacknav:{screen:stacknav}

  },
  {
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
    drawerWidth: 300,
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    }
   });

   const stacknav = createStackNavigator ({   Splash :{ screen:  Splash},
    Dashboard: { screen:  Dashboard},
      Readmore: { screen: Readmore },
      Tabs: { screen: Tabs },
      Search: { screen: Search } });



  export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Getting an Error of this 
[image: Error]

Comment: Need to know how you are calling the 2nd Page from 1st and 3rd page from 2nd Page. This will give clarity. One possible issue that could be is, you are popping the second page after/before navigating to 3rd page. So please update your question.

Comment: I navigate to the third page via the second page and second page via the first page. @Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and before that, there are some things that we need to watch. 
**Make sure every const Name start with Capital Letter**
I couldn't just simply import the stack navigator to the drawer navigator from the same file.
So I put the stack into another file and export default it directly into my Drawernavigator.
And that fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple
 Put all the screens of your drawernavigator inside a new createstacknavigator.
Then inherit stack navigator inside drawernavigator as a child.
I.e

```
 const stacknav = createStackNavigator ({   Splash :{ screen:  Splash},
    Dashboard: { screen:  Dashboard},
      Readmore: { screen: Readmore },
      Tabs: { screen: Tabs },
      Search: { screen: Search } });

Const appNavigator = createdrawernavigator({ stacknav:{screen:stacknav}},{ ...}}
```

Hope it helps. Sorry for poor code structure as i am replying from a mobile device. But surely it ll be of your help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use createStackNavigator instead of createDrawerNavigator.

Comment: Create both drawer and stack. Put  that drawer in stack brow. Share your code if you need some more help.

Comment: the above is my full code of routing page how can I modify I tried but do not seems to be working.